# Setting the User_id into the create action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails, so sorry for the silly question.

I have 3 models an employee, employer and keychain model.

A keychain belongs to both and employee and employer.

and the employee and employer has many keychains

I'm wanting to set the employee_id in the create action but I'm having trouble.

```
class Keychain < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :title, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}

 attr_accessible :employee_id, :employer_id, :issued, :revoked, :title

 belongs_to :employer
 belongs_to :employee


end
```

This is the create action for the keychain

```
  def add_keychain

  @keychain = Keychain.create(params[:keychain])
  @keychain.employer_id = current_employer.id
  @keychain.employee_id = 
  @keychain.title = params[:title]

  @keychain.save

  redirect_to employees_path

end
```

Schema

```
create_table "keychains", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.date     "issued"
t.boolean  "revoked"
t.integer  "employee_id"
t.integer  "employer_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
```

end

The form is in the show action of the employees. and i can get that current employee's id by <%= @employee.id%>

But i can't get the id in the create action.

Again sorry for the novice question.

Answer (score 0):

The technique I have used for passing foreign keys like employee_id is to use a hidden field in the form.

Maybe something like this in your Employees controller:

```
  class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
      @key_chain = @employee.key_chains.build() #@key_chain has @employee's id now.
    end
  end
```

This embedded form for keychain in your Employees#Show view:

```
<%= form_for(@key_chain) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :employee_id %>
  <%= f.label "Title:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form as I configured it routes to the KeyChains#Create controller:

```
  def create
    @key_chain = KeyChain.new(key_chain_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @key_chain.save
        format.html { redirect_to @key_chain, notice: 'Key chain was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @key_chain }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @key_chain.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```